# matching two files contents using matlab and outputted the result as a matrix

Tags: file, matlab, matrix, match

I am new to Matlab. I need your help to solve my problem. I tried to implement several codes but unfortunately I could not be able to find the solution.

I have a file and I need to compare each row with the remaining and output the results as a matrix contains 1s of matched items and 0s otherwise. If two rows are overlapped using the 2 and 3 columns as shown in the example,the matrix has 1 . For example I have the following rows in the file.

1   X    10   20   A

2   Y    15   20   T

3   C    25   40   A

the output should be:

```
    1    2     3       

1   0    1     0

2   1    0     0

3   0    0     0
```

Really I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your overlapping rules... To me it looks like you only have an overlap between rows 1 and 2, and rows 2 and 1, and NOT between rows 2 and 3, and rows 3 and 2, as your output matrix would seem to suggest.

Comment: Yes, you are right I had a mistake.there are no rules between 2 and 3

Comment: I have corrected the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it

```
% open file
fh = fopen('test.txt');

% read data (adjust 10000 if necessary)
dat = textscan(fh, '%d %s %d %d %s', 10000);

% extract high and low values
hi = dat{4};
lo = dat{3};

% create grid
[ hig, log ] = meshgrid(hi, lo');

% compare high, low
overs = ~(log >= hig);

% check both ends & zero out diagonal
res = overs & overs' & ~logical(eye(length(hi)));

% close file
fclose(fh);

res
```

Comment: Why does the syntax highlighting screw up here?

Comment: Many thanks gzm0 for your helpful code. But how can I modify this code to take two input files, one in xls and the other in txt. Because the data are separated into two files, xls and txt.I want to do the same thing but now with two files

Comment: Use `xlsread` to read the excel file and then massage `dat` into the correct form. Please also accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I mean If the data is seperated between two files one is xls and the other is txt. How can I modify the code to deal with two files at the same time and outputs the same matrix

Comment: You have to assign the variables `lo` and `hi` correctly. So instead of having one `dat` coming from one file and taking elements 3 and 4, you'll have `dat_txt` and `dat_xls` and you take one row each for each of `lo`, `hi`.